# Why doesn't gem install bundler work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to deploy an application via Github pages, and based on this tutorial that I am watching, I need to install bundler first.

When I type in the command `gem install bundler`, I get the error:

> While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

I do not have rbenv downloaded and I don't know how to. I also do not fully understand the concept of gems.

How can I bypass this issue?

Comment: Quick answers to your sub questions.  [This Link](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation)  is the installation process  for rbenv.  But rbenv is only necessary if you have multiple projects on the same machine that require different ruby versions.
In ruby the word `Gem` is basically `Library` and `Bundler` is a `Gem/Library` management tool to ensure that your gems are downloaded, versioned properly, and not conflicting.  [This Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) explains ruby gems in greater detail

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very simple and helpful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'sudo gem install bundler'

Comment: He is using system version of ruby which is no good. I think in a long run its better for him to install ruby with `rbenv` or `rvm` then to use `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. I've run `rbenv versions` and was shown: - * system, - 3.0.6. After typing `rbenv global 3.0.6`, I ran `gem install bundler:2.2.19` again and it was a success.